# Why use Context.MODE_PRIVATE or Context.MODE_WRITABLE?

Tags: java, android, facebook

What I understood about `context.MODE_PRIVATE` or `MODE_READABLE, WRITABLE` is that those functions make files for sharedprefrences.

I am wondering what the difference is between `context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` and `getSharedPreferences(KEY, 0);`.

`getSharedPreferences` retrieves its preferences from a xml folder as far as I know. And `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` stores its files. And why use `context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` if both `getSharedPreferences(KEY, 0)` and `context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` makes files.

Below is part of the Facebook API where I noticed `Context.MODE_PRIVATE`.

```
public static boolean save(Facebook session, Context context) {
    Editor editor =
        context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
    editor.putString(TOKEN, session.getAccessToken());
    editor.putLong(EXPIRES, session.getAccessExpires());
    return editor.commit();
}
public static boolean restore(Facebook session, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences savedSession =
        context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    session.setAccessToken(savedSession.getString(TOKEN, null));
    session.setAccessExpires(savedSession.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
    return session.isSessionValid();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `Context.MODE_WRITABLE` or `Context.MODE_READABLE` according to the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html). So I assume that you are talking about `Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITABLE` or `Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE`.  (Not that this is actually relevant to your question ...)

---

> I am wondering what is the difference between
>
> ```
>     context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
>     context.getSharedPreferences(KEY, 0);
> ```

There is no functional difference.  `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` is an `int` constant with value zero; refer to the javadoc linked above for the details.  The former is more readable though, and that makes it preferable from a code style perspective.

Comment: @SehoLee - *"so... there is no functional difference between them?"*  That is what I just said ...