# How to make sure app is reading the same file it wrote into?

Tags: android, file, android-activity, java.util.scanner, file-read

I need to save a list. I use file to do so.

For writing, I'm using code1.

For reading, I'm using code2.

Both code1 and code2 are different function from same class, which I use from different activities.

The problem is, when I write the list in one activity, and try to read it in another, the contents differ.

code1

```
    public void write(Context context, SwitchList list){  // Switchlist is custom class of two separate lists
        FileOutputStream file = context.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
        ...  
        writer.close();
        file.close();
    }
```

code2

```
    public SwitchList read(Context context){
        FileInputStream file = context.openFileInput(name);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        ...
        scanner.close();
        file.close();
    }
```

If I have written list [1, 2, 3] in one activity, I expect to read [1, 2, 3] form another activity.

But what I get is [1].

Comment: Is `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1]` _exactly_ what's being written/read? If not, please [edit] in _exactly_ what's being written/read – it might help (if it's too big/confidential, create an [MCVE] using dummy data to show the problem). Some guesses: is it possible that the writer and reader overlap in how they are called? Is the fact that one "open" call has `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` and the other doesn't significant?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what is being written/read.
I don't think there is any overlapping, since after it has written, PrintWriter is closed in same function. And reading is not happening, until after another activity is started.
And I do not know about "MODE_PRIVATE".

Comment: I'm not an Android expert; my thoughts are "generic debugging ones"... If you're reading `[1]` then that suggests – as you believe – that there's no overlapping (as opposed to say reading `[1, `). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8697078/2096401) suggests the use of `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` makes no difference. That more-or-less leaves **(a)** `name` is somehow different between the two calls (log/trace/display its value somehow) or that **(b)** the write failed, leaving an older version of the file to be read (ensure you would detect any such failures).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use different file names as [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files) says

```
val filename = "myfile"
val fileContents = "Hello world!"
context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use {
        it.write(fileContents.toByteArray())
}
```

use static constant file names variables so it can be accessed from both activities for example:

```
const val FILE_ONE = "file_one"
const val FILE_TWO = "file_two"
const val FILE_THREE = "file_three"
```

Comment: I think you did not understand the problem.
I want the filename to be same.
And to read from one activity, what is written from other activity.
Both code1 and code2 are from same class, which is only for reading and writing.

Comment: it is not about code, it is about making different filenames for different files so same file would not be overwritten

Comment: @AntonisRadz The OP doesn't _want_ different files... they want to write something to a file in one part of the code, then read that data back from _the same file_ at another point in the code. Whether using a file is the best way of doing this, I don't know, but using _different_ files certainly isn't.

Comment: @TripeHound you are correct.

But, if not file(or db, which I will use only if there isn't any solution for file), how do I preserve list when app is not being used?

Comment: @KamalyeshKannadkar As I say above, I'm not an Android expert, but I believe _Shared Preferences_ is possibly the way to go. Perhaps see [this Medium blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/sharedpreferences-is-your-answer-to-simple-storage-a7c8499ea8ff) or the official docs.

Comment: It depends for what purpose file has been saved. Shared Preferences is  basically ment for saving configurations or other small amount of information.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out, the problem was in Scanner object.
Not the Scanner object, but the fact that I am using Scanner object.

I was using

```
scanner.next();
```

which was causing it to read

```
"[1,"
```

I just had to replace it with

```
scanner.nextLine();
```

and it is working correctly.

**Thank you for your efforts.**

Comment: Should have put complete function in the question. Though, at the time, I though it not important enough to affect such.